# Maybe I'm missunderstanding C++ Exceptions?

Tags: c++, xml, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to wrap my head around exceptions and more I guess what they can do and even more important what they should and shouldn't do.

So, I'll go off with an example of how I am thinking at a pretty specific problem and hope that people will either bless or bash the ideas I'm having.

I'm reading settings off of a xml file, so I might have the settings but there is also the case where the specific setting might not be in there and that'd yield some troubles and a lot of "point-error-handling" or what to call it, of the type:
(observe: this is not "real code" but just some pseudo stuff hopefully making my point).

```
if (xml.attribute("some_attrib")) {
    settingForSomeAttrib = xml.attribute("some_attrib")->value();
} else {
    settingForSomeAttrib = "some default value";
}
```

So this will leave me with a check and an assignment more or less for every- and anything I'd like to do, which isn't desirable.

Then I were thinking, perhaps I could run through it all, fetch anything which went wrong and hand it the default value, a bit of a just try to get it right and anything which didn't work out we'll handle afterwards..

Leading me to a `try/catch` type of thinking.

I am then thinking that perhaps I can do a try block:

```
try {
    setting1 = xml.attribute("attr1")->value(); // throws some kind of "attr1" exception?
    setting2 = xml.attribute("attr2")->value(); // -||-                "attr2" exception?
} catch (???) {
    //go through the things which went wrong and set them settings straight!
}
```

Hope that makes some kind of sense, or at least that it's possible to follow my train of thought. I feel that it's not really how exceptions are meant to be used.

I am thinking that my question is kind of two folded by this:

1) Is exceptions usable like this or is this just a bad idea?
2) how do people usually go about this in C++ to get code that aren't all bloated in checking for validity?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd certainly not use exceptions to handle settings that are merely optional.

Comment: In your `try/catch` example, if the `settings1` line generates an exception, then all following lines will NOT get executed due to the exception. So you're left with putting a `try/catch` around each attribute get which is the same as your `if/else` above. What I would do is initialize everything FIRST, then run through trying to pull from XML and if the value doesn't exist it won't matter. EDIT: I also like @NPE example below.

Comment: In general, use exceptions for unexpected (or, dare I say, exceptional) situations. You should expect optional attributes to be missing, so that is not an exceptional situation.

Comment: Thanks that's pretty much what I needed to hear, along with the answers I feel all set :)

Comment: Exceptions should be used in exceptional circumstances. The clue is in the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would certainly not use exceptions to handle settings that are merely optional.

Instead, I would do something along the following lines:

```
string getString(const XML& xml, const string& attrib, const string& defaultAttrib) {
  if (xml.attribute(attrib)) {
    return xml.attribute(attrib)->value();
  } else {
    return defaultAttrib;
  }
}

...
setting1 = getString(xml, "attrib1", "attrib1_default");
...
```

Comment: `default` is a keyword and cannot be used outside a switch statement, though VC++ allows it (probably treating it as a contextual keyword). Anyway, this solution works well because an overload can be provided that does not have the `defaultAttrib` parameter, and in the `else` branch instead throws an exception.

Comment: @GManNickG: Good catch re `default`, thanks (oddly enough I had it called something else, but then decided to shorten the name to `default` to make the declaration fit in the code box... d'oh! :-))

Comment: Very helpful, that does really give me the clean implementation I wanted, and handle the errors without me ending up with bloated code. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

I've occasionally seen exceptions used in such a way, but I don't think it would be necessary or desirable here, especially since it seems like you'd have to go through all your various settings, or manually keep track of where you stopped.

How about

```
setting1 = attribute_value(xml, "attr1", default1);
setting2 = attribute_value(xml, "attr2", default2);
```

where `attribute_value` would encompass the logic to figure out if `"attr1"` exists.